# How can I create a running median of diel cycle from multiyear data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, zoo, smoothing

I think this problem may be of interest to others who deal with data smoothing of long-term environmental variables.

I have a dataset structured as below:

Columns:

```
Date    Hour_Min    Y(response variable)
```

These data are hourly, and I need to create a moving average of the diel cycle, but categorized by the Hour_Min.  In other words, if I were to use a 31 day window, for a given day the running average data point for Hour_Min 00:00 would take the average of the day in question with the data points from Hour_Min 00:00 for the previous and the following 15 days.  This would then repeat for that day's hour 1:00, etc. through the dataframe.

Unfortunately the data also have many NAs, which is problematic for moving window averages, although I think that can be solved using rollapply from the zoo package.

One approach I tried was to use tidyr's spread function to switch from long to wide format, to create a dataframe like this:

```
Date    Y_Hour_Min_0000    Y_Hour_Min_0100    Y_Hour_Min_0200    etc...
```

If I could change the format in this way, I could then create new columns of running averages of each Y_Hour_Min_.... column.  I would then need to gather everything together back to long format (another task I'm not sure how to approach).

However, I wasn't able to get the spread function to work so that it kept Date as a grouping variable associated with each Y_Hour_Min_.... column.

Another, possibly more elegant solution would be if there is a way to create a single new column in one step, using some combination of rollapply and custom function.

Any thoughts on how to implement code for this task will be greatly appreciated.  Below I have a simple code to simulate my dataset:

Simulated data:

```
### Create vector of hours/dates:

date <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-12-30 
23:00"), by="hour")

### Create vector of noisy sine function:

d <- 365
n <- 24*d # number of data points
t <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*d*pi, length.out=24*d)
a <- 6
b <- 1
c.norm <- rnorm(n)
amp <- 3
y <- a*sin(b*t)+c.norm*amp+15

### Randomly insert NAs into data:
ind <- which(y %in% sample(y, 1000))
y[ind]<-NA

### Create test dataframe:

df <- data.frame(dt = date, y = y) %>%
  separate(dt, c("date", "hour_min"), sep=" ") %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

Comment: for the NAs.. if you had `c(4, 5, NA)`, and you were looking at the 5 spot and a window of 1 behind and ahead, would you want 4+5/2 or 4+5/3? using rollapply it seems that it would be 4+5/2, as it would ignore the NA using `na.rm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work:

**EDIT:** Simplified code by adding `fill = NA` parameter to `rollapply()` function as suggested in the comments.

```
# add a complete date + time stamp
df$date_time <- paste(df$date, df$hour_min)

# make new column to store median data
df$median_y <- NA

# set rolling median width
width_roll <- 31

# do a rolling median for each hour, one at a time
# add NAs where no median can be calculated
for (i in levels(factor(df$hour_min))) {
  df[df$hour_min == i, "median_y"] <- rollapply(df[df$hour_min == i, "y"],
                                                width = width_roll,
                                                median,
                                                na.rm = TRUE,
                                                fill = NA))
}
```

The approach is just to use the `rollapply()` function as you suggested, but only on one particular hour at a time. Then each of these is placed back into a new column in turn.

Here's an example for just one hour over the whole year, which makes it easier to visualize the median smoothing.

```
# Examples:

# plot one hour plus rolling median over time
# here i = "23:00:00"
plot(x = as.POSIXct(df[df$hour_min == i, "date_time"]),
     y = df[df$hour_min == i, "y"],
     type = "l",
     col = "blue",
     ylab = "y values",
     xlab = i)
lines(x = as.POSIXct(df[df$hour_min == i, "date_time"]),
      y = df[df$hour_min == i, "median_y"],
      lwd = 3)
legend("topleft", 
       legend = c("raw", "median"), 
       col = c("blue", "black"), 
       lwd = 3)
```

[Plot for a single hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhwf2.png)

This is for everything (lots of data so not so easy to see but looks like it worked).

```
# plot all the data
plot(x = as.POSIXct(df$date_time),
     y = df$y,
     type = "l",
     col = "blue",
     ylab = "y values",
     xlab = "Date")
lines(x = as.POSIXct(df$date_time),
      y = df$median_y,
      lwd = 3)
legend("topleft", 
       legend = c("raw", "median"), 
       col = c("blue", "black"), 
       lwd = 3)
```

[Plot for all data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OilVE.png)

Comment: Thanks! I edited the answer to include the suggestion. Not sure how I missed that option the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it but its not perfect. Hoping someone can come in and top me off.

**TL:DR;**

```
df2 <- df %>% slice(-7441) %>% spread(hour_min, y)

mov_avg <- function(x) {c(rep(NA, 15), rollapply(x, width = list(-15:15), FUN = mean, align="center", na.rm=T), rep(NA, 15))}

avgs <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lapply(df2[,2:ncol(df2)], mov_avg)), nrow = nrow(df2), byrow = FALSE))
colnames(avgs) <- paste0("avg_", colnames(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]))

final_df <- cbind(df2, avgs) %>%
  gather(2:ncol(.), key = "hour_min", value = "value") %>%
  arrange(date, hour_min)
```

**In Depth:**

Starting at your starting point.. I added `set.seed(1)` so we can all follow along in tandem.

**Your Initial Starting Point:**

```
### Create vector of hours/dates:
set.seed(1)
date <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-12-30 
                                                       23:00"), by="hour")

### Create vector of noisy sine function:

d <- 365
n <- 24*d # number of data points
t <- seq(from = 0, to = 2*d*pi, length.out=24*d)
a <- 6
b <- 1
c.norm <- rnorm(n)
amp <- 3
y <- a*sin(b*t)+c.norm*amp+15

### Randomly insert NAs into data:
ind <- which(y %in% sample(y, 1000))
y[ind]<-NA

### Create test dataframe:

df <- data.frame(dt = date, y = y) %>%
  separate(dt, c("date", "hour_min"), sep=" ") %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

First thing was to do what you said and try the long format. Normally I think this problem would be best by using `dplyr`'s `group_by` on the `hour_min` column and doing the rolling average there, but I'm not sure how to do that.

First thing I noticed is that there is a duplicate value for one row on a given day. There are two observations for 1am, which breaks our `spread`, so I removed that observation using `slice(-7441)`

So let's spread your df.

```
df2 <- df %>% slice(-7441) %>% spread(hour_min, y)
```

As we can see, the dataframe is now 365 observations long(dates), and 25 columns wide (date + 24 hours)

```
dim(df2)
[1] 365  25
```

Next thing I did which is where this isn't perfect, is using `rollapply`. When using rollapply we can give it a `width = list(-15:15)`. This will look 15 days into the past and 15 into the future and average all 31 days together. The problem is the first 15 days don't have a past 15, and the last 15 days don't have a future 15. So I padded these with `NA`s. I'm hoping someone can fix this part of my answer.

I created a custom function to do this:

```
mov_avg <- function(x) {c(rep(NA, 15), rollapply(x, width = list(-15:15), FUN = mean, align="center", na.rm=T), rep(NA, 15))}
```

If we just do the `rollapply` we will get a vector of length 335. I padded 15 in front and back to get us to our needed 365.

Next we want to `lapply` that function across our entire dataframe. That will give us a list of 24 vectors of length 365. We then want to turn that into a dataframe and bind it to our current dataframe.

Lastly we `gather` all of the columns back into the long format and `arrange`

```
avgs <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lapply(df2[,2:ncol(df2)], mov_avg)), nrow = nrow(df2), byrow = FALSE))
colnames(avgs) <- paste0("avg_", colnames(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]))

final_df <- cbind(df2, avgs) %>%
  gather(2:ncol(.), key = "hour_min", value = "value") %>%
  arrange(date, hour_min)
```

I hope this helps.